# xamarin,Can debug with simulator on windows visual studio?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have Visual studio 2017 on windows and have a mini mac.

I installed xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android to windows.

Then can debug android application with emulator on visual studio success fully.

I installed xamarin studio community and update recent version xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android.

Then i could connect to mac from visual studio by xamarin agent.

I thought that finally readied to debug IOS app by simulator.

But don't appearance IOS simulators list.

[image]

So, I want to be sure that, Is it possible that debug with simulator on visual studio(windows) without "Remoted iOS Simulator"? I know that is require VS enterprise but i don't have.

Waiting your comment, Thank you.

Comment: Currently its only available in Enterprises version https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/

Comment: Shiwanka Chathuranga // oh...Then Is it the only solution build and debug on mac PC. If it true i will give up hurry this and move my source files to mac..Thank you.

Comment: Xamarin development in VS for MAC is very fast and enjoyable.... only lack is more intelisense support, but its avoidable